# LM1117 same output as input

Tags: ldo

I have an [L298 Dual H-Bridge DC Motor Controller](https://www.robotshop.com/en/l298-dual-h-bridge-dc-motor-controller.html) which comes with an LM1117-5 voltage regulator. I want to use this regulator for a [logic level converter](https://www.robotshop.com/en/logic-level-converter-bidirectional.html) to go from 3.3v to 5v.

I have one board that outputs 3.3v which is connected **with its own power supply** and I have the L298 connected to another power supply where I get the 12v that it requires.

I tested their respective outputs individually and I got 3.3v and 5v. The thing was when I connected 3.3v to the logic converter and the 5v from the L298, I connected gnds coming from different power supplies to have the same voltage reference. When I was testing the output of the logic level converter I noticed that the high voltage was 12v rather than 5.

I disconnected everything and now I can see that the output from the LM1117 that it is on the L298 is the same as the input (12v) rather than 5v.

Could it be the cause of this that I connected grounds from different power supplies?. I believe I must do that, right?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT 1: Here is a schematic. Control board is a development board which comes with its own 12v@1A power supply. It has multiple digital outputs (pmods) which also includes 3.3v and GND pins. On the other side it is the L298 which I connect to a 12v power supply which the board contains a 5v voltage regulator and I connected grounds of both boards via the logic level converter.
From [this thread](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3682/question-different-ways-of-connecting-l298n-motor-driver-board-to-arduino-and-mo) I can confirm that it was correct to connect all GNDs so I don't get what might have happened with the voltage regulator on the L298 board.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYAcll.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question to add a circuit diagram. Otherwise, you're asking people to piece together your circuit in their head from all this text. The schematic editor here is a breeze to use. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did not see the schematics editor. It was really easy to draw it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: According to the datasheet, LM1117-5.0 has a minimum load current of 5 mA. Try loading the output with 1kOhm to see if the voltage goes down to 5V. If it doesn't, then the LM1117 might be busted, but I have no idea how that could have happened. Does the logic level converter still work?

Comment: I checked level converter datasheet: 12V should not have harmed it. However L298 needs a 5V logic supply. If this 5V comes from LM1117 and it is now 12V, then L298 may be dead with an internal short from its 12V to 5V pins. Please do a quick continuity test on unpowered board to confirm whether 12V and 5V are shorted together.

Comment: They are in fact shorted....The multimiter does not buzz but it shows a low number (~600). Now that I think, when it was on a GND wire was disconnected and I connected it back. Could that have been the issue? I also checked the regulator before connecting it and I got 5v so it was working and without any load.

Comment: 600 is not a short.

Comment: So it is not shorted then... Could have been the issue that GND was in the air and I reconnected? Maybe a spike of current burnt the regulator?

Comment: 600 on continuity mode is 0.6V thus not a short, but one diode drop. Where did you put the + and - multimeter wires? + on 5V and - on 12V or the opposite?

Comment: "The multimiter does not buzz but it shows a low number (~600)." - does operating the blue push-button make any difference? What do you get if you reverse the meter leads?

Comment: The board has a power on switch that I missed. When - is on output and + on input I get ~15 and + on input with - on putput I get ~80. Could it have been that gnd was disconnected and I reconnected again the cause?

Comment: I've just tried with an external LM317 and everything works. I made sure to have all the connections secured.